# Cos'è un "riccopellone"?

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> Ho visto i miei fratelli – Talarico e Amedeo erano con me. Gli è scoppiata la pancia perché abbiamo mangiato l’intonaco della chiesa. Loro sono morti, e io no – perché io sono duro come un diamante e posso digerire anche i sassi. Non ho paura dei morti. Non ho paura di nessuno. E non me ne fotte niente di rubare a un **riccopellone** fetente. Bravo, dice Rocco, scrollandoselo di dosso. Dimostramelo.

Qualcuno di voi mi saprebbe spiegare il significato di "riccopellone"? Non ho trovato questo vocabolo su nessun dizionario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [questo dizionario dialettale](https://m.dialettando.com/dizionario/detail/?id=11352) si trova:

> **Campania**  
>   ricco che ostenta le proprie ricchezze: *riccopellone*

Cercando invece Ricco Pellone, [in questo poema in lingua napoletana](https://books.google.it/books?id=oXItAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA326&lpg=PA326&dq=riccopellone%20poema&source=bl&ots=4tWDaKHbph&sig=ACfU3U3HXsag9i7FwbExoWzjuF9iMx95iQ&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwit_q3MjYnhAhVmMOwKHZxhDcYQ6AEwCnoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=riccopellone%20poema&f=false) datato 1787 si può leggere:

> Nzomma potemmo stare a pparagone 
> A Ccrasso, a Mmida, a lo Ricco
>   Pellone

e ciò fa riferimento alla [parabola di Lazzaro e del Ricco Epulone](https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola_di_Lazzaro_e_del_ricco_Epulone) raccontata nel Vangelo secondo Luca.

Infatti, nella voce "pullóne" di questo [*Lessico e Letteratura del Dialetto Napoletano*](https://www.academia.edu/38424281/P-_Lessico_e_Letteratura_del_Dialetto_Napoletano) di Salvatore Argenziano e Gianna De Filippis si trova:

> **pullóne:**        *nom. pr.* 
>    Trasformazione di Epulone che ricorre nella parola *riccopellone*
>    per “ricco Epulone” di cui al Vangelo. 
>          G. D’Antonio: *e ghiennosene palillo palillo lo Scossato a ccercare lo veveraggio a la figlia, ped averla maritata co sto Ricco Pullone.*

La citazione è di un [testo Settecentesco](https://books.google.es/books?id=8Pr3PNCxDiEC&pg=PA248&lpg=PA248&dq=D%E2%80%99Antonio+%22Ricco+Pullone%22&source=bl&ots=bctIsFpXNe&sig=ACfU3U1IKtZpIIVXfd4Gr6Y5Qx1Vrc1jmQ&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwieyK-njYnhAhWsxoUKHTOhBMUQ6AEwBHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=D%E2%80%99Antonio%20%22Ricco%20Pullone%22&f=false) di [Giovanni D'Antonio, detto il Partenopeo](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/d-antonio-giovanni-detto-il-partenopeo_(Dizionario-Biografico)/).

***Riccopellone*** è quindi una distorsione di Ricco Epulone, come sinonimo di uomo molto ricco che in vita non ha provato pietà e misericordia per i poveri.

Comment: Interessante... Non sapevo che l'uomo ricco che appare nella parabola di Lazzaro avesse il nome di Epulone.

Comment: Infatti, nella citazione del Vangelo di Luca che appare su Wikipedia non appare il nome di questo personaggio.

Comment: L'espressione appare anche in questo testo Settecentesco di [Giovanni D'Antonio detto il Partenopeo](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/d-antonio-giovanni-detto-il-partenopeo_(Dizionario-Biografico)/): https://books.google.es/books?id=8Pr3PNCxDiEC&pg=PA248&lpg=PA248&dq=D%E2%80%99Antonio+%22Ricco+Pullone%22&source=bl&ots=bctIsFpXNe&sig=ACfU3U1IKtZpIIVXfd4Gr6Y5Qx1Vrc1jmQ&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwieyK-njYnhAhWsxoUKHTOhBMUQ6AEwBHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=D%E2%80%99Antonio%20%22Ricco%20Pullone%22&f=false.

Comment: Nel testo del link precedente appare come "Ricco Pullone", che assomiglia di più a "Epulone".

Comment: Vedi la voce "pullóne" su questo [*Lessico e Letteratura del Dialetto Napoletano*](https://www.academia.edu/38424281/P-_Lessico_e_Letteratura_del_Dialetto_Napoletano) di Salvatore Argenziano e Gianna De Filippis. Penso sia una fonte con una informazione interessante da mettere nella risposta.

Comment: Non so in questo contesto specifico, ma in generale [“epulone”](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/epulone/) è un nome comune – un tipo di sacerdote –, non un nome proprio.

Comment: Mi sono presa la libertà di aggiungere quello che avevo trovato su quel *Lesssico e...* perché mi sembra interessante per sostenere alcune delle tue affermazioni. Naturalmente, puoi fare tutte le modifiche che vuoi.

Comment: @Charo Ottimo lavoro!!!

Comment: @DaG In questo caso però il significato è il secondo ("goloso, che ama i banchetti") :)

Comment: In particolare, il primo verso della parabola è, nella Vulgata, " Homo quidam erat dives, qui induebatur purpura et bysso, et **epulabatur** quotidie splendide." (Lc. 16:19)

Comment: @DenisNardin: Ah, giustissimo, ma è in ogni caso un nome comune, e comunque derivato per traslato da quello dei sacerdoti, che si occupavano appunto di banchetti.